# What is the difference between "javascript:", "#", and "javascript:false" in iframe.src attribute

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser

If I want to set the `src` of iframe with these 3 value. I found:

1. `javascript:` doesn't work in IE10 (error is can't find the page). other mainstream browsers or IE9 is ok.
2. `javascript:false` will show a `false` string in the iframe for IE10, others browsers or IE9 is ok.
3. `#` works fine in all the browsers.

What is the difference between them? Which one is the best choice for cross-browser issues?

Comment: 4. Don't set a `src` attribute at all

Comment: What for would you need to set an iframe `src` to an invalid URI?

Comment: But sometimes the javascript library we have to use like `ext js` include this kind of script to set `src` attribute. thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang - please tell us the real problem you're trying to solve?  What function in what library and why are you creating an iframe with no src.

Comment: As others have implied: this smells like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I was using the `ext js 2.x` in my website, but found the `Ext.SSL_SECURE_URL` is initialized with `javascript:false` by `ext js`. this code caused a problem in the IE10. which is some window of  `ext` shows a string `false` (I found it is because of the code `iframe.src=javascript:false`). so I changed `Ext.SSL_SECURE_URL` value to `javascript:`. the `false` string would gone . but found another problem .  it would show a error page "IE can't show this page". thanks.

Comment: Just curious: what about `javascript:""`? This still uses the JavaScript Protocol - which I believe is "valid" in context - but specifies a program body (unlike `javascript:`) and should yield an empty string as opposed to "false" (from `javascript:false`).

Comment: :P `javascript:""` is difference from `javascript:` (I mentioned in my question.) ???

Comment: @Joe.wang Yes. `javascript:""` has a single expression (an empty string) in the body, while `javascript:` has an empty body. The different versions of IE may  be treating this differently (e.g. in the case of IE10+, not accepting the latter). I suspect that this is an incompatibility introduced in IE10 for a JavaScript Protocol with an empty body.

Comment: That should actually work, although if you really just want a blank document, the standard `about:blank` is the way to go. Using a `javascript:` URI scheme to get a blank iframe is extremely weird, and someone should probably file an issue with any library that does that.

Comment: @DaggNabbit @user2864740 :P Thanks your clarify. One of solution for this issue is just extending the library, It doesn't need change the original code(`javascript:false`) of it . and 2.x is really old version for the `extjs`. The latest version of it is up to 4.x. Another solution I think maybe trying to upgrade to 4.x in my website. Because exj team announce 4.x support IE10 . Thanks.

Comment: Any reasons for changing mind to down vote? If somebody would like to tell me . It will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Avoid using `javascript:false` as this will break websites that do not allow inline javascript in their `Content-Security-Policy` header. Therefore it's a bad idea to use this in scripts that you expect other parties to include.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `about:blank` as the URL. This should display a blank page in all browsers.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6694#section-3

Answer (score 3):

If you want an `iframe` that doesn't load anything right away, then just don't set the `src` attribute to anything.  You can set the `.src` property later via Javascript to cause it to load something.